# Bug when using await/async for System.Net.Http with .NET Core (.NET Standard 1.4 and .NET Framework 4.6.1)?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

Foreground: I was investigating a bug in an ASP.NET Core project (targeting .NET 4.6.1, using assemblies from .Net Standard 1.4), that threw a MissingMethodException, although this in no way could be possible. Isolating the faulting method, I took the core of the code out to a separate unit test which also targets .NET 4.6.1.

The exception I receive, `ThreadAbortException`, from the unit test is more or less this (it sometime various):

```
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.SetRequestHandleDecompressionOptions(SafeWinHttpHandle requestHandle)
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.SetRequestHandleOptions(WinHttpRequestState state)
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__103.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Hub.Test.UnitTest1.<FetchUrlAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

The code in question for the abolve exception:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        //FetchUrl(); // works
        var task = FetchUrlAsync(); // does not work
    }

    private void FetchUrl()
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler, true))
        {
            var response = client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("https://github.com/dotnet/core"))).Result;
            Trace.WriteLine("FetchUrl:" + response.StatusCode);
        }
    }

    private async Task FetchUrlAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler, true))
            {
                var response = await client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("https://github.com/dotnet/core")));
                Trace.WriteLine("FetchUrlAsync: " + response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice, that if I call FetchUrl() the code works. Yes, I know this became a sync method the moment i invoked result, but it is for demonstration purpose only.

However, the faulting method, FetchUrlAsync(), keeps throwing a ThreadAbortException.

Reason for SendAsync is, that the original implementation is a generic one using this one method for all the Http* work. The same error can be triggered with GetAsync and so forth.

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here, but I suspect this error to be a bug somewhere in the .NET CLR.

UPDATE

Although the unit test problem was solved (thank you), I still experienced issue in the ASP.NET Core web-api. From my understanding, .NET Standard 1.4 and .NET Framework 4.6.1 should be 1-1 compatible. This is why i believe there is a rare bug in the framework, although it seems unlikely.

The common denominator is System.Net.Http; and this varies bitwise from .NET Standard 1.4 and .NET Framework 4.6.1; and I tend to find out what the problem is and post the answer to others that might struggle with a similar problem.

Comment: Well, for a start you are not `await`ing the task.

Comment: In one method `response` is a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` and in the other it's a `HttpResponseMessage`, but you seem to treating them both the same.

Comment: @juharr Note the `.Result` on the end of the non-async method.

Comment: your test runner quits before task is complete

Comment: i like how quickly people assume bugs in the framework =\

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, failed to scroll over.

Comment: You have to *await* `FetchUrlAsync` otherwise the test will exit before `SendAsync` has a chance to return

Comment: Touché, Oleg .. I have just been staring blind on this one. My apologies. Reason for this "fast" conclusion was, that I have found several features with .NET Standard 1.4 and .NET Framework in terms of the common API.

Comment: Thank you guys; hopefully others can learn from my mistake.

Comment: For your update, you need to show us the code where you are using it all the way up the call stack. You are likely missing a await in your real code like you where in the unit test. You should have awaits all the way up till you have a `async Task<ActionResult>`

Comment: @Scott; the await problem was solely in the unit test project. All controller methods uses either Task<IActionResult> or Task. I have a good grip on the async/await, although I failed in the unit test. Problem was, as described in my own answer, related to the common API between .NET Standard 1.4 and .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: LOL - please no more "you must await" responses... if you answer that then you don't understand the problem fully...and have likely not tried it with the .NET Standard setup as Michel has it configuered... I know / have been using async/await since introduced, and also just ran across this bug... very frustrating.  Has me re-thinking .Net Standard projects for Xamarin.. i may just move back to PCL Xamarin.Forms projects as .Net Standard still feels too raw...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, to solve the original issue which was a `MissingMethodException` reported by one of the controllers.

*This error was ONLY triggered when using the async/await combination, which make sense because of the compiler generated code behind the scene.*

Turns out, that one of the Nuget assemblies was using `System.Net.Http` from `.NET Standard Library 1.6.1` and this assembly package targeted .NET Standard 1.4 (which, on paper, is 1-1 compatible with `.NET Framework 4.6.1`).

I then mingled with the solution, and was able to produce a `FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.`

So far so good.

The problem became apparent when looking the bin/debug folder. There was no System.Net.Http.dll to be found, as it was using the built-in Framework assembly.

Aha.

**VISUAL STUDIO 2015**

Looking through the solution, only reference to the built-in Framework assembly was in the project.lock.json:

```
    "frameworkAssemblies": [
      "System.Net.Http"
    ]
```

This reference came from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/1.1.0` and `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols/2.1.0`.

Removing these two `frameworkAssemblies` entries made the solution work, as the "real" System.Net.Http.dll was now copied to the bin/debug folder.

**VISUAL STUDIO 2017**

Almost the same problem; but since Microsoft has deprecated the use of project.json, the solution here is to modify (or add) an app.config file with the following content:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I am sorry guys for this long post; but there is a bug - and it might not be in the framework .. evidence might point to msbuild and/or different IDE's. I am just happy i found the error and was able to correct it.

I hope this rather long entry can help others with similar issues.

Happy coding!

Comment: More info for .NET Standard: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/

Comment: For .net Standard 2, use <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0"/>

Answer (score 1):

The test method doesn't await for the asynchronous method to finish, so the test ends before `SendAsync` has a chance to return.

You don't specify which testing framework you use but I assume it supports asynchronous tests. In this case change your test method to :

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    await FetchUrlAsync(); 
}
```

If it doesn't, you'll have to use `Wait()`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    FetchUrlAsync().Wait(); 
}
```