# WebClient, httpWebRequest AND external zabbix .exe failing to get connection on network disk

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, zabbix

So I'm having a weird issue with my .NET Core 2.0 Console application after I upgrade my Windows 10 from 1709 to 1803 the other day. I know I could downgrade, but I rather see the problem to be fixed and not be postponed.

Let me try to explain the situation and please note that English isn't my native language so grammar mistakes will be made. I have a internship where we have a list with mutiple clients, their last backup date and if these where succesful etc. The information for this application, my application, is coming directly from the Zabbix app on one of our servers. Before the information is being e-mailed to my collgaues and before Zabbix is even being called, I get some of the information from another server, with both AhSay 6 and 7 servers running. That info is being send to Zabbix. So: Ahsay 6 and 7 -> Zabbix -> email. Here comes the problem: on my C:\ disk and on the server responsible for running the app it's working fine, but because my company does not work with git (strange isn't it?) I do my work, testing etc on a external, network connected, disk (located on H:\ ). I also have a backup disk, located on D:\ . Both on my D and H disks the application is giving multiple errors saying httpWebRequest, WebClient etc doesn't have the correct parameters. Also the external .exe from Zabbix, Zabbix_sender.exe is failing to connect. Again: this runs fine on another server, AND on the same computer but with the local C disk.

So my question: is it possible the Windows 10 upgrade has screwed my app or am I doing things wrong.

I will, on request, give you code. But because of company regulation etc this has to be slithly edited, I'm working on that.

Happy coding and thanks in advance,

Thaha Jemni

**EDIT, on request some code with error given:**
The code to get a list of users from AhSay,
Error code given (in log file):

```
System.Net.WebException: An error occurred while sending the request. Er is een ongeldig argument opgegeven ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Er is een ongeldig argument opgegeven
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.ThrowOnInvalidHandle(SafeWinHttpHandle handle)
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.EnsureSessionHandleExists(WinHttpRequestState state)
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered>d__59.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.<SendRequest>d__194.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadBits(WebRequest request, Stream readStream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 chunkSize, Byte[] header, Byte[] footer)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(Uri address, String method, NameValueCollection data)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(String address, String method, NameValueCollection data)
   at zabbixMailer.sender.GetInfo.ListUsers() in H:\source\zabbixMailer\zabbixMailer\sender\GetInfo.cs:line 212
```

With code:

```
public static dynamic ListUsers()
    {
        Logger log = new Logger("log.txt");
        try
        {
            string URL = "example.org";
            string method = "POST";

            var SysUser = "user";
            var SysPwd = "password"; //URL AND PASSWORD/USER CHANGED! NOT REAL ONES!

            NameValueCollection sys = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "SysUser", SysUser },
                { "SysPwd", SysPwd },
                { "LoginNameOnly", "true" }
            };

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            byte[] _json = client.UploadValues(URL, method, sys);

            string json = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_json);
            dynamic info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            return info;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            log.ErrorToFile(e.ToString());
            log.TextToFile("Programma gesloten met code -1");
            Environment.Exit(-1);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The 'Logger log = new Logger' comes from a custom class that logs certain errors to a file called 'Log.txt'. After the error accured, evirement.exit is called so it'll quit imidatily after the first error (this one) is being called.

Again: this is not the case on my C drive, it runs just fine.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Normally here I would lean towards Windows upgrade screwing up your app because you are doing something wrong. But then again it could be some security policies with non-local drives that became stricter in the upgrade.

Comment: What you say would not be strange, considering the Server running this code is not on windows 10 1803, maybe even not on Win10 at all.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700869/bug-when-using-await-async-for-system-net-http-with-net-core-net-standard-1-4 help?

Comment: I don't quite understand the link between my question and his. Are you saying I found a bug in .NET or are my references not correct?

Comment: I am wondering whether the latter might be factor or not.

Comment: <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0-preview2-26406-04" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Caching" Version="4.5.0-preview2-26406-04" />

Comment: These are two that i use for caching that are depending on a preview version. Could that be it? A bug in a preview version of configuration manager?

Comment: Check that the network share is on a server that your machine trusts.